# Android : Sorry Application Keyboard in Process (Force Quit / Wait)

Tags: android, android-emulator

When a try to deploy my android App in the emulator, after the application(.apk) gets loaded in to the emulator, when i tap on the menu button in emulator for loading my application's initial screen, its is raising me a alert message with this information,

```
<pre>Sorry Application Keyboard in Process (Force Quit / Wait)..</pre>
```

and some other similar messages too..

What does it mean,can anybody help me...How can i avoid this issue that is happening at all time,

When this happens,unless i tap on Wait button, i can't able to proceed.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens because the application is doing something on the UI thread that is taking a long time. If you are loading a lot of data when your app loads you should do it in a background thread so you can display a loading screen to the user and leave the app responsive.

Comment: This is the answer for my own post, since my RAM capacity is limited, i had this type of Problem,once i upgrade my RAM, i got my problem solved..Thanks for your support and time..To run android in your machine you need atleast 2 GB-RAM to avoid performance issues..., this is the minimum configuration that i have mentioned, you may need more than that..to avoid performance issues.. Thank u...